# How to make adapter with different number of views in each of item in list view

Tags: adapter

I want to make a list view with different number of views in each item.Like this

ListView

listitem1:
TextView1
TextView2
TextView3

listitem2:
TextView1
Button

listitem3:
TextView1
TextView2

I have tried to use the baseadapter and addview on the getView method but it doesnot work and it create more views than I want. I dunno whether there is a way to do it on using the adapter. I cannot find any solution in stackflow and I want someone can give me an simple example for me. Thank you.